# Inventory Problem: How to group ungrouped and aggregated data

Tags: database, dataframe, aggregate, grouping, inventory-management

I am trying to group data into a dataframe. The data I imported is an excel sales report from Quickbooks Enterprise (14th Edition). The format contains Q1, Q2, and Q3 data for this year. The columns are Qty, Amount, % of Sales, Avg Price, Cogs, Avg Cogs, Gross Margin, Gross Margin %. The next quarter then starts, notice, after the T column.

My rows also have groupings by Inventory, Machines, Other products, etc.

The quarters also have their own 8 columns of qty, amount, etc.

For the life of me, I cannot seem to know of a way to group these based on their appropriate inventory and slicing every 8 columns for the respective quarter. Any help is much appreciated!

[Jan-Mar 22 portion, followed by Apr-Jun with the same columns](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FlNu7.png)